# Is there a way I can make only one CSS style class to accommodate different section tiles on a web page?

Tags: html, css

I am working on a web page with various section titles: About, Projects, Contact, etc.

These titles will be on top of a background image. I want them to stand out. So, I want to fill the background with white. 
(The titles' text are dark blue.)

The problem is that, if I only designate a background-color, the elements stretch across the page. I need them to each have a custom width (with the 3px padding of white around them). Do I have to have a separate CSS style class for each title with a width designation?

The titles are all < h3 > elements.

Here is the CSS style I have now:

```
 .sectionTitle{

background-color: #ffffff;
padding: 3px;

}
```

Comment: can you set a snippet, a codepen or a fiddle, with fake text and fake image to help us to help you ? fake text/image :  http://html-ipsum.com/ http://dummyimage.com/  http://lorempixel.com

Comment: Perhaps you may declare `h3.sectionTitle { display:inline-block; }` but it is hard to tell as I do not know anything about structure and layout and html and css.

Answer (score 0):

Your `h3` tags stretch across the page because they are `block` elements (naturally 100% width of parent).

If you force your `h3`'s to display as `inline-block` elements, their width will shrink to the minimum needed to accommodate the text node within - I imagine this is what you are trying to achieve.

```css
body {
  background: #e6e6e6;  
}

.sectionTitle {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h3 class="sectionTitle">
  Some title
</h3>
```

Of course this can potentially cause issues depending on the rest of your markup so you may have to wrap your `h3` in a `block` element such as a `div` to keep your title in it's own row.

```css
body {
  background: #e6e6e6;  
}

.sectionTitle {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <h3 class="sectionTitle">
      Some title
    </h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want each title to have different padding you can just create a separate class for the color and padding.

```
    .sectionTitle{
      background-color: #ffffff;
    } 
    .padding3{
      padding: 3px;
    } 
    .padding3{
      padding: 2px;
    }
```

Then assign the color class to each heading and the specific padding class

```
    <h3 class="sectionTitle padding2">Hello</h3>
    <h3 class="sectionTitle padding3">Hello</h3>
```

Or if you want each heading to have the same padding just assign them all to the css class you have provided above.